# Multiple Instances of my javascript wrapper

Tags: javascript

the problem is override's the second dialog `args` over first one, when close second dialog the alert show dialog name passed by create method , and when close first dialog the name also show's the last dialog create name.

```
var Dialogs = Dialogs || (function () {
    var _args = {                       //default args
        name: "globalDialog"
    }

    var dialogName = "";

    return {

        create: function (args) {
            _args = args;
           dialogName = '#' + _args.name;

            // create hide listener to current dialog attached to it's name
            $(document).off('hidden.bs.modal', dialogName);
            $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', dialogName, function (e) {
                alert(_args.name); //this show the last dialog name created 
            });


            return this;
        }

    };
}());
```

//USAGE

```
Dialogs.create({name:"Dialog1"}); //create first dialog
Dialogs.create({name:"Dialog2"}); //create second dialog
```

this code above creates tow dialogs (modals) over each other

I know this problem its around static members shared by class, and need to be instantiated every time i need to create new dialog ,but in `JavaScript` is not available to do this .

there's any solution or idea to acheive what i'am looking for .

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/3L6jsmzx/)?

Comment: almost yes, i will try this solutions. @Teemu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use OOP:

```
    function Dialogs(args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    Dialogs.prototype.hide = function() {
        for(var i = Dialogs.queue.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if(Dialogs.queue[i - 1] === this) {
                Dialogs.queue.splice(i - 1, 1);
            }
        } 
    }

   Dialogs.prototype.show = function() {
      this.hide();
      Dialogs.queue.push(this);
   }

   Dialogs.queue = [];
   Dialogs.showActiveName = function () {
       if(Dialogs.queue.length) {
           alert(Dialogs.queue[Dialogs.queue.length - 1].args.name);
       }
   }

    Dialogs.create = function(args){
        var out = new Dialogs(args);
        Dialogs.queue.push(out);
        return out;
    }

    var dialog1 = Dialogs.create({name: "a"});
    var dialog2 = Dialogs.create({name: "b"});
    dialog1.show();
    Dialogs.showActiveName();
    dialog2.show();
    Dialogs.showActiveName();
    dialog2.hide();
    Dialogs.showActiveName();
```

Comment: Can you combine this code with my code block above ? to understand more clearly
@degr

Comment: I will try, but I can't understand what your code do.

Comment: i wrote this code jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nxpwsa2u/1/ see when closing dialogs alerts